# Find customer id(s) who spent maximum amount in a given month

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to calculate customer id who spent maximum amount in june month.

Data set:

```
May-2017-120-245.50                                
Jun-2017-124-21.50                                                                
Jun-2017-110-34.00                 
Jun-2017-120-200.00      
Jul-2017-124-546.50  
Jul-2017-110-1500.00  
Jun-2017-124-245.50
```

Code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("MapFunction").master("local").getOrCreate();
val data = spark.read.textFile("E:\\Sample - Copy.txt").rdd
val monthFilter = data.filter(line => line.contains("Jun"))
val ratings = monthFilter.map(x => (x.toString().split("-")(3),x.toString().split("-")(2)));
```

I don't know how to get the result. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your sample data consists of multiple transactions by the same customer in a given month, the following solution involves first loading the text data into a DataFrame, filtering for the target year-month, summing up amounts per customer, and finally getting the row(s) with the maximum total amount:

```
// /path/to/textfile
May-2017-120-245.50
Jun-2017-124-21.50
Jun-2017-110-34.00
Jun-2017-120-200.00
Jul-2017-124-546.50
Jul-2017-110-1500.00
Jun-2017-124-245.50

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "-").csv("/path/to/textfile").
  toDF("month", "year", "cust_id", "amount")

df.
  where($"year" === "2017" && $"month" === "Jun").
  groupBy($"cust_id").agg(sum($"amount").as("total_amount")).
  withColumn("amountRank", dense_rank.over(Window.orderBy($"total_amount".desc))).
  where($"amountRank" === 1).
  show
// +-------+------------+----------+
// |cust_id|total_amount|amountRank|
// +-------+------------+----------+
// |    124|       267.0|         1|
// +-------+------------+----------+
```

Note that `dense_rank` is used to cover cases in which multiple customers have the same maximum total amounts.